# Create custom menu tab on a users profile page in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am a Drupal newbie. I have written a custom module in Drupal 8 and it works and displays some content.

I want to add a tab in the user's profile that links to my custom module.

As far as I understand, I need to write a route and a task. This is what I have done :

**my_module.routing.yml**

```
my_module.some_route_name:
  path: '/user/{user}/some_path'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyModuleController::content'
    _title: 'Some Title'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    user: \d+
```

**my_module.links.tasks.yml**

```
my_module.some_task_name:
  route_name: my_module.some_route_name
  base_route: entity.user.canonical
  title: 'Some Title'
```

I have done this and the route works as it should, however **no tab shows up** in my user's profile page.

It should look something like this :

[image]

### Edit 1

I have partially resolved the issue by creating a hook as per Drupal API 8.6 (menu_local_tasks_alter) and this is what I wrote :

```
function my_module_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name, \Drupal\Core\Cache\RefinableCacheableDependencyInterface &$cacheability) {

$url = Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('my_module.some_route_name');

if ($route_name == 'entity.user.canonical') {
$data['tabs'][0]['my_module.some_route_name'] = [
    '#theme' => 'menu_local_task',
    '#link' => [
    'title' => t('Some Title'),
    'url' => $url,
    'localized_options' => [
        'attributes' => [
        'title' => t('Add content'),
        ],
    ],
    ],
];

// The tab we're adding is dependent on a user's access to add content.
$cacheability
    ->addCacheTags([
    'user.permissions',
]);
}
```

}

This works if I replace the {user} part of my route's path with 1. When I have {user} in the path, it now complains with the following error :

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br></br><em class="placeholder">Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException</em>: Some mandatory parameters are missing (&quot;user&quot;) to generate a URL for route ...
```

### Edit 2

I have also made sure to provide my content method in my controller with a user object $user that implements AccountInterface as described here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/using-parameters-in-routes , however, I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the hook, I just tested with your *routing* and _task definitions and it works fine for me.

This is my controller:

```
class MyModuleController {

  public function content($user) {
    return [
      '#markup' => "user: $user"
    ];
  }

}
```

This renders as: "*user: 1*" at the "*/user/1/some_path*" URL.

I think you are also trying to use [Drupal's automatic paramater upcasting](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameter-upcasting-in-routes), but that is optional.

#### MissingMandatoryParametersException

To solve the exception (Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException). 
You have to add the mandatory parameter in your route. Just add the user (`['user' => 1]`):

```
$url = Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('my_module.some_route_name', ['user' => 1]);
```

Comment: Yes ! Thanks this works. I changed it to get the current logged in user like this :

$user = Drupal::currentUser();
$url = Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('my_module.some_route_name', ['user' => $user->id()]);

Comment: thanks, I am busy checking if I can remove the hook.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the additional parameters from my Controller which is no simplified as you explained. However, It seems I still need the hook, else the local task / tab does not show up in my user profile page as one of the tabs... In any case, you have helped me a lot !

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone stumbles on this in the future, here's an easier way that doesn't require the `HOOK_menu_local_tasks_alter` implementation, and corrects a typo in the OP's code:

### my_module.routing.yml

```
entity.my_entity.my_route:
  path: '/admin/my_entity/{my_entity}/my_route' # Or similar
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyController::content'
    _title: 'My Route Title'
  options:
    parameters:
      my_entity:
        type: entity:my_entity
  requirements:
    _permission: 'my_permission'
```

### my_module.task.yml

Note the singular `task` not `tasks` in the OP's post.

```
entity.my_entity.my_route:
  route_name: entity.my_entity.my_route
  base_route: entity.my_entity.canonical
  title: 'My Route Title'
```

Then write your controller as you would in @cesar-moore's post, with the first parameter upcast, as he notes, as `MyEntity $my_entity`. No need for any alterations. This route will now show a new tab on every page of your entity: View, Edit, or similar.